# Jmeter and database

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to know the mechanism of performance testing Database by Jmeter, so need your help on my concern as below:

Q1. Does Jmeter will access ***directly*** to Database for testing ? Or,

it will access to database ***via a website*** having database URL (as the Database URL on JDBC request config) ?

Q2. which fields will be tested in Database : capacity or Database structure or others ? - please explain in advantage.

Besides, Jmeter is a good tool for testing database ? - **which cases / why should** we use ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**: JMeter has [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler which can connect to database **directly** assuming appropriate [JDBC driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) in JMeter classpath and proper [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

**Q2**: It's totally up to you as JMeter doesn't test anything. If you specify a query or a set of queries under [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) JMeter will report the time which queries took under the load and errors if any.